# LXDE-pi -- cannot show desktop on local monitor, but VNC is fine

Tags: pi-3b+, lxde, electron

I'm setting my RaspberryPi 3B+ (Debian Buster) up as a [magic mirror](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror). I've run into a really weird issue that I can't wrap my brain around.

The magic mirror software is basically an EletronJS app, configured to run full-screen when LXDE-pi loads up. I have a monitor connected directly to the RPI, and have been configuring it via SSH.

I can set up the app to render various non-fullscreen components, and it renders properly on my monitor. Its appearance over VNC looks identical.

Adding any full-screen component causes my local monitor to display the new content momentarily -- before blanking to a black screen. Over VNC, the app displays properly (i.e., in fullscreen with the new content).

If I "restore" the ElectronJS app over VNC -- i.e., make it non-fullscreen and un-maximized -- then it suddenly appears on my local monitor.

If I resize the app window over VNC, I will see it resize on the local monitor -- up to a certain size, at which point the whole monitor goes black again.

---

`/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash

@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
# @unclutter -idle 0.1 -root
```

The app is re-/started/stopped using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), which in turn delegates to a shell-script -- `~/mm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/MagicMirror
DISPLAY=:0 npm start
```

Finally -- my HDMI resolution is set to be DMT Mode 47 (1440x900, 60Hz) -- `/boot/config.txt`:

```
...

hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=47

# We ran into trouble using the experimental GL driver; so we're using the legacy, non-GL version
# dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

gpu_mem=256

# Finally -- the display is rotated 90 degrees CW to a portrait orientation
display_rotate=1
avoid_warnings=1
...
```

Comment: I am going to try re-imaging the O/S completely. Could be I touched something I don't remember.

Comment: Well, that just broke everything. Now my monitor works just fine when booting (i.e., when displaying text) -- but the moment the desktop environment loads, I get a blank screen.
VNC works just fine.

Comment: Yup -- it looks like -- when I'm displaying any image (e.g., a desktop background) -- I can achieve a screen resolution of no greater than 1024x768 (DMT mode 16). (and that with max GPU memory of 256MB, and without the experimental GL driver)

(edit: CEA mode 19, 1280x720, is achievable; I'm going to have to stick with that)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why this would be the answer, but it's working now.

I had to radically moderate my expectations w/r/t display resolution.

It seems that, so long as I'm displaying nothing complicated -- e.g., white text on a black background -- I can use higher resolutions (like that 1440x900@60Hz I was using before).

But the **moment** I try to display any image that fills more than so-much of the screen, the screen blanks completely. (This appears to be related to the HDMI controller rather than X, because my VNC sessions are unaffected.)

The only way I can achieve image-display is by adopting a lower resolution; in my case, by going with CEA mode 4 (1280x720@60Hz).

Note that this is after bumping my allocated graphics RAM to the maximum (256MB), and disabling the experimental GL driver.

My `/boot/config.txt` ends up looking like:

```
#hdmi_safe=
#disable_overscan=
#overscan_left=
#overscan_right=
#overscan_top=
#overscan_bottom=
#framebuffer_width=
#framebuffer_height=

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=6

# ...

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
gpu_mem=256

display_rotate=1
```